# Consistently get index out of bounds exception on timed row deletion

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a button in each row of a tableview. When the button is clicked, a timer that deletes the row is set for two seconds. However, if the user begins reordering the cells, the two second timer is invalidated, and a 0.1s timer to delete the row is set the moment they stop reordering. However, I am now getting the following error right after the 0.1s timer happens :

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 0 which only contains 2 rows before the update'
***`

If reorder any cells that are not marked as completed, this error does not happen. However, if I switch any cell with the cell about to be deleted, this error occurs.

```swift
    // The moment the checkbox animation is finished
    func animationDidStop(for checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {

        let cell = checkBox.superview?.superview as? TasksTableViewCell

        var iP = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)

        if(iP?.row != nil){

            let id = tasks[iP!.row].id
            var index = tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id})!

            if(tasks.indices.contains(iP!.row)) {

                if(self.tasks[index].isCompleted == true) {

                    // Delete row after 2s
                    weak var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: ["id":id], repeats: false)


                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                        if(self.isReordering == false) {

                            while(self.isReordering == false) {
                                if(timer?.isValid == nil) {
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        //Invalidate 2s timer
                        timer?.invalidate()

                        if(self.tasks.indices.contains(index)) {
                            while(self.tasks[index].isCompleted == true) {

                                if(self.isReordering == true){

                                    // Wait until they are done reordering
                                    while(self.isReordering == true) {
                                        // Do nothing
                                    }

                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                        index = self.tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id})!

                                        print("Index to delete: " + String(index))

                                        // Delete row after 0.1s
                                        weak var secondTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fire), userInfo: ["id":id], repeats: false)

                                    }
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Removes completed task from table after n seconds
    @objc func fire(timer:Timer) {

        let userInfo = timer.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        let id:String = userInfo["id"] as! String

        if(tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id})) != nil {

            let index:Int = tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id})!

            if(self.tasks.indices.contains(index)){
                if(self.tasks[index].isCompleted == true) {
                    self.tasks.remove(at: index)
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: index, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I change the 0.1s timer to 1.0s it works, but I want it to happen instantly.

Comment: Maybe duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960853/swift-attempt-to-delete-row-0-from-section-0-which-only-contains-0-rows-before

Comment: Don't think so @ovo, that user is using a nested array.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is the reason without knowing your updating code. But one reason might be that you do not update your data model during the reordering. This code is cited from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301607/tableview-app-terminated-due-to-nsinternalinconsistencyexception):

```
// tell the table view you're going to make an update
[tableView beginUpdates];

// update the data object that is supplying data for this table
// ( the object used by tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: )
[dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// tell the table view to delete the row
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath 
           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

// tell the table view that you're done
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Maybe you should check in your reordering code if you update your data model in time.